# Python Pandas How to combine multiple string rows into one

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to load this data into a pandas data frame:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoXpl.png)

A sample column

"

2019

Market

Share

"

Trying to get that into "2019 Market Share"

I was wondering how I can get those strings on different rows into a single row?

I am using this code to import the data from the data shown in Image.

```
def load_data(year):   
    csv_path = f"assets/US_States_Visited_{year}.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(csv_path, header=3,skipfooter=8)
    df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.iloc[0:3].values)
    df=df.iloc[3:].reset_index()
    return df
```

This code is what I am doing with no success so far.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add the data as code-formatted text? That would allow copy-pasting the data for easier testing.

Comment: Is this the result you want? `df['new_col'] = df['2019 Rank'] + '-' +  df['STATE/TERRITORY VISITATION'] + '-' + df['2019 MARKET SHARE']`